# Why are the textviews invisible?

Tags: android

I use the following layout (shortened):

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" ...>
  <TableRow ...>
    <TextView
      android:id="@+id/sell_text"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:text="@string/sell" />
    <SeekBar
      android:id="@+id/sell"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </TableRow>
 </TableLayout>
```

Like this (shortened also):

```
LayoutInflater inflater = parent.getLayoutInflater();
View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.merger_sale, null);
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(parent);  
builder.setTitle(R.string.sell_stock_after_merger)
.setView(layout)
.setPositiveButton(R.string.sell_all, new OnClickListener() {...
.setNeutralButton(R.string.trade_sell, new OnClickListener() {...
.setNegativeButton(R.string.trade_all, new OnClickListener() {...
AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
dialog.show();
```

The layout has no errors, nor does the code. The layout shows exactly as it should in Eclipse's layout editor.
The dialog appears when it should appear, buttons behave how they should, except for the texview (@+id/sell_text) [and the other textviews in the shortened <TableRow>s], which don't appear.

What am I overlooking? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think it would work if you change the width and height to wrap content instead of match_parent.

match_parent means it would be fillparent which may fill the entire layout.

Or try giving weights to each item like layout_weight with value as 0 .This may work either

Answer (score 0):

try it:

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

  <TableRow ...>
    <TextView
      android:id="@+id/sell_text"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:text="@string/sell" />
    <SeekBar
      android:id="@+id/sell"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </TableRow>
 </TableLayout>
```

Comment: tablerow overrides layout_width and layout_height attributes of its children.